# Mesuring the distance between a base line and an object

Tags: image-processing

I am working on an image having musical symbols, like[image: Before i reach this step i have removed the staff lines to recognize them in efficiency.]

Before i reach this step i have removed the staff lines to recognize them in efficiency.
but now i want to detect on which stave line they exist. They only way i am thinking of is to create a base line, let's say to be the ground of the image. And measure the distance between the object and the base line.

Maybe i can add contour boxes and measure from the base of the box till the ground of the image.

How can i implement this idea?? What algorithm can i use ?

Comment: take a look at a similar work, it is a Stanford student project report: https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Project_Spring_1415/Reports/Stramer.pdf